# Run multiple R Scripts in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having a lot of R Scripts created by RStudio, and I am wondering if there is a method to run all of them in RStudio with a single step instead of open and run each of them one by one.I know that I can copy and paste them together into one same script, but it will make it too large and it's also a time consuming step.
Thank you!

Comment: To organize your code, we have one mantra: Write. A. Package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could have one main script that `sources` the others and just run the main script.

main.R

```
print("Hello main")
source("blah.R")
source("foo.R")
```

blah.R

```
print("Hello blah")
```

foo.R

```
print("Hello foo")
```

---

Run them all by sourcing `main.R`

```
> source("main.R")
[1] "Hello main"
[1] "Hello blah"
[1] "Hello foo"
> ?source
```

source {base}

> source causes R to accept its input from the named file or URL or connection. Input is read and parsed from that file until the end of the file is reached, then the parsed expressions are evaluated sequentially in the chosen environment.