# Run and change variables in R scripts loop

Tags: r

I want to run my main R script multiple times to get an interval (the output of this script is an avgerage (numeric number)). However, within this main R script, I access others sub-R scripts with `source()` by following this ([Run multiple R Scripts in R Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665702/run-multiple-r-scripts-in-r-studio)).

Here's the problem: I use `set.seed()` in every sub-R scripts to make sure I get the same number across all sub-R scripts. And now I want to run `set.seed(1)` to `set.seed(10)`. How can I do this?

Desired output (just the idea):

```
    main R script:
for (i in 1:10){
    source("\...\sub_R_scrip1.R")
    source("\...\sub_R_scrip2.R")
    ...
    source("\...\sub_R_scrip10.R")
}

   sub_R_scripX:
set.seed(1) # when i = 1 in the loop of the main R script
train.row = sample(nrow(df), 100)
train.data = df[train.row,]
test.data = df[-train.row,]
xtrain = train.data[,1:49]
ytrain = train.data[,50]
xtest = test.data[,1:49]
ytest = test.data[,50]
```

How can i approach this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `function`s instead of `source`ing your code? It's much easier in the long run.

Comment: @r2evans there will be a lot of things to return if using function instead of source, there are ~200 lines for each sub R script

Comment: *"lot of things to return"* is all relative, but only you can know what is required from each function. I don't know your scripts, your code, so it's always more complicated than it seems. I don't know enough to be able to help much, sorry. I can say this, though: you can have quasi-arguments for a file by starting it with something like `if (!exists("args")) args <- list(...) ; if ("seed" %in% names(args)) set.seed(args$seed)`, where your main script can set `args` to be the "arguments" used to initiate each source file. It's a hack.